# Difficulties reading a contents of text file into 2*2 array

Tags: c, pointers

I encountered some difficulties reading a chars from a text file into a two-dimensional dynamic array -- it fails with "Unhandled exception at 0x011d155d in Problem_03_life.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfdfdfdfd."

Here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

if(argc <= 1) printf("Program needs two arguments: input file and output file!");

FILE* f;
f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(f == NULL) printf("File cannot be opened!\n");


/* Determining how many lines and length of string */ 
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
char c;
while((c = fgetc(f))!=EOF) {
    if(c == '\n') {n++;}
    else m++;
}
m /= n; // counting quantity of chars in one line

/* here i'm allocating memory for array (am i right?) */ 
char** field = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *(field + i) = (char*)malloc(m*sizeof(char));
} 

int i = 0, j = 0;


for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= m; j++){
        *(*(field + i)+ j) = fgetc(f); // Here i get an error
    }
}

fclose(f);
```

}

Here is a contens of a file (i need to read white spaces too):

```
*************
* ##        *
*           *
* #         *
*************
```

What am i doing wrong using a ponters to read into it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one problem with your code:

- **The second for goes "one-too-far". Change "<=" to "<"**
- You're depending on the fact that each line has the same length. Once different lines have different lengths you'll run into trouble
- You're using a char to store the return value of `fgetc`. `fgetc` returns `int`
- You're trying to call `fgetc` after it already returned `EOF`. By definition it can only return `fgetc`. You need to rewind or consider a different strategy

Also, you're making it harder than it has to be:

- `*(field + i)` can be written as `field[i]`
- `*(*(field + i)+ j)` can be written as `field[i][j]`

Comment: Do you mean i need to go back to the start of a file before loops? And how can i make it? And thanks -- all other things i changed.

Comment: @DimaReshetnikov Look into `fseek` or `rewind`.

Comment: Do i need fseek() function to set position to the beginning of a file?